# Can I build emulator version of LineageOS?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, lineageos

I've tried `brunch lineage_x86-userdebug`, but I can't run it using

```
emulator64-x86 -verbose -show-kernel
```

The emulator goes black screen, and it says

```
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the availa...
```

I wonder how to build a emulator x86 version on Ubuntu with lineageOS 16.0.

Comment: The [patch that enabled emulator images to be built as an SDK add-on](https://review.lineageos.org/c/LineageOS/android_vendor_lineage/+/256909) has still not been merged on the LineageOS 16.0 branch but has been [merged on 17.0](https://review.lineageos.org/c/LineageOS/android_vendor_lineage/+/265299).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little out of date, but did you try building the emulator device?

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_generic_emulatorx86

Note you made this commit which sits on a fork.

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_generic_emulatorx86/commit/2f41407581d7f8fee34d8d8868e234d071a99b3b